# "Wasted time" report Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have heard rumors of an Eclipse plugin that will provide statistics on how much time a developer is working vs how much the IDE is forcing the dev to wait by building the workspace, or loading Java retooling, loading a file editor, etc...

Does this plugin really exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using the [Lack of Progress Bar](http://lopb.org/) for this. It works as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this?: [Rabbit-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/rabbit-eclipse/)

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitri said, [Lack of Progress Bar](http://lopb.org) is probably what you are looking for. It will track how long it takes for Eclipse jobs to complete. Generally, most operations like checking-in code, building a project, deploying to your server from within IDE, etc... all run in background jobs.  Basically, all we did was hook listeners into the Eclipse background jobs manager to record start/stop times for jobs and then show the time elapsed in a view. It is pretty simple and you can look at the source code [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lopb/) if you want to.

I wrote the plugin with a couple of buddies a few years ago. I have not maintained it since. If you run into any issues just contact me via the contact form on the LOPB site and I will do my best to help you out.